# What is data.json.gz firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I received an existing firebase project from another developer. I was setting up a bucket for making backups programmatically and I found a bucket named "backups" where I find these documents with extension data.json.gz that are created every day at 3 am, but I'm not sure what they are, does anyone know what they could be?, Client is asking me if there a backup of the database, but as far I know firestore backups have an extension named overall_export_metadata

[image: bucket files]

Comment: They may have written a custom backup job that exports the data as a JSON file and scheduled it with a cron. What I would do is open one of those up on a GCE instance to inspect the data and determine whether its data that is coming from a custom backup or perhaps something else.

Comment: That's another strange thing that there's no cron job, today I set up the first one. Do you know how can I open those files?

Comment: gzip -d filename.gz should do it.

Comment: @JairoPy, did the previous comment answer your question? If so, please post it as an answer in order for community members with similar questions will find this helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Alexander N, (for Linux) hit gzip -d filename on your terminal, this will create the ungzip file, and you'll be able to read the data. In this case, these files are backups from one of the firestore collections and the firestore DB rules.